# Get Position of row from query

Tags: mysql

I have a database that looks like the following:

```
+-------------------+------------+-----------+-------+------------+------+
| SteamID           | Name       | Map       | Time  | Date       | id   |
+-------------------+------------+-----------+-------+------------+------+
| 76561198059749096 | BÃ¸lle     | surf_mesa | 51.74 | 1454877544 | 3757 |
| 76561198141936247 | SlachtHuis | surf_mesa | 51.76 | 1454783151 | 2110 |
| 76561198059749096 | BÃ¸lle     | surf_mesa | 51.83 | 1454876964 | 3729 |
| 76561198065863390 | dLGHT      | surf_mesa | 51.98 | 1455017166 | 4988 |
| 76561198059749096 | BÃ¸lle     | surf_mesa | 51.98 | 1454877206 | 3741 |
| 76561198065863390 | dLGHT      | surf_mesa | 52.02 | 1455017046 | 4986 |
| 76561198141936247 | SlachtHuis | surf_mesa | 52.03 | 1454839146 | 2838 |
+-------------------+------------+-----------+-------+------------+------+
```

This has thousands of results in for each map (Note the table isn't already sorted by time), what I'm wanting to do is select a SteamID and find his fastest time for the selected map. This would then return the total position out of all the other times.

So for example, I want to get 76561198065863390's position or rank out of all other times for surf_mesa. This would return a table or something similar to:

```
+-----+-------------------+
| pos | SteamID           |
+-----+-------------------+
| 4   | 76561198065863390 |
+-----+-------------------+
```

I started messing around with queries and came up with  this:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
    SELECT (@pos:=@pos+1) pos,Map,Time
    FROM `surf_times`
    WHERE `SteamID` = "76561198065863390"
    ORDER BY `Time` DESC
) `surf_times`
WHERE `Map` = "surf_mesa" LIMIT 1
```

Got myself confused in that query and seemed to get further away from the answer :)

Comment: if @user1372896 and Slach are both your accounts, you can merge them. Follow [I accidentally created two accounts; how do I merge them?](http://dba.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts).

Comment: Perhaps you wanted `Bølle` instead of `BÃ¸lle`?

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT pos, SteamId
FROM
(
    SELECT (@pos := @pos+1) pos
        , Map, Time, Date, SteamID
    FROM `surf_times` S
        , (SELECT @pos := 0) p
    WHERE `Map` = "surf_mesa" 
    ORDER BY `Time` 
) `surf_times`
WHERE `SteamID` = "76561198065863390"
ORDER BY pos
LIMIT 1;
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9d082/1/0)

Comment: Seems to be returning a 4517 and 4518, this map should only have 900~ results. The position of that steamid should also be 3~ thanks

Comment: what is 4517 and 4518? The query works with your sample. Perhaps it must filter on Map as well in the subquery (not clear from your question) fiddle as been added. final order by pos was missing.

Comment: The position is 4517 or 4518, it also now shows 4091. I'm not sure where it is getting that number from as there is only 980 results in total for surf_mesa and 8831 results in total with other maps.

Comment: for 76561198065863390, number 4 is 51.98 for time and number 6 is 52.02  when order by time

Comment: That seemed to work, was my example incorrect? Thanks for your time

Comment: if you remove the limit and where steamed =... you see row 4 and 6 with steamed 76561198065863390. pos 4 as 51 and pos 6 has 52. so I think your sample result should be 6 ?

Comment: do you have 2 account @slach? you can merge them

Comment: @user1372896 you can up vote and accept if ti works.

Comment: @user1372896 You must login as and merge accounts if you got more than one.